# Switch between two low voltage signal sources

Tags: relay, solid-state-relay

I'm new to this community so I apologize if this isn't posted correctly.

I am looking for a circuit that could switch between two low voltage (1v or less) DC inputs to a single output. Oxygen sensors such as the type used for car engines use a chemical element that generates a small voltage dependent on the amount of oxygen present. While the engine computer for my application only has one o2 sensor channel, I need to supply computer with the signal/voltage from two o2 sensors; switching between the two at least twice per second.

Since even a small variance in the signal output would cause an issue, there would need to be minimum resistance/voltage loss in the circuit. Is this possible, and if so what could the circuit look like?

Comment: you mention 'DC' inputs. Any idea what the frequency spectrum os the O2 sensor signal is? A few Hz, less, more? How will the computer know which sensor it's reading? Does the computer supply a signal which you can use to switch between the two?

Comment: @RJR according to his description "chemical generates a small voltage..." it's an analog potential, varying only due to higher/lower O2 concentration (think zinc-air battery), so in  this case the 'frequency' is likely in the millihertz-to-hertz range.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an analog(ue) switch - these are basically open/closed contacts in silicon controlled from a logic signal: -

[image]

There are sub-1ohm varieties but you can buffer the signal (in or out) with a high impedance op-amp circuit.

Functionally they look like this (DG273): -

[image]

But can be much more complicated offering the ability to multiplex several signals to one line. [**Here**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjk1fK07_HKAhXMPRQKHcU_BvwQFgggMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fsg%2Fslyb125d%2Fslyb125d.pdf&usg=AFQjCNG3LZuCPzWL1XRO_C20Cud7drX0eg&sig2=K-c4l2oCKiMA_F1wXSwxuQ) is a guide from Texas Instruments.

Comment: Thank you for your response Andy. So the switch will automatically alternate between the sources when power is applied? Which of the terminals is output to the computer? Sorry to bother, I have a very basic understanding of this stuff and this is somewhat beyond my comprehension.

Comment: It won't be automatic - it has to be controlled by you and, if you want to "sample" A followed by B you could build an oscillator that alternately switched between the two inputs.